# iPhone activity modal badge

Tags: iphone, uikit

When turning off mail / calendars from an Exchange or MobileMe account in Settings, you will see a "Turning off mail..." badge appear over all view elements while the process is occurring. The badge intercepts all touch events while it's visible.

I've seen this replicated a couple of times in other apps and was wondering if anyone had any pointers on how to create and display such a badge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll probably want to do is create a transparent UIView with your badge that spans the entire screen. This way you can catch touches anywhere on the screen and redirect them to the badge (and probably just dispose of them altogether). You can use a UIActivityIndicatorView to show progress in your badge while you process.